My discord.py bot gives a runtime error when trying to use aiohttp package
I tried to use an api for my discord bot using nest_asyncio and aiohttp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\main.py", line 296, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 869, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 858, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 786, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 620, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 816, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 642, in request
    data = await json_or_text(response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 107, in json_or_text
    text = await response.text(encoding='utf-8')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 1086, in text
    await self.read()
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 1044, in read
    self._body = await self.content.read()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\TPLbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 357, in read
    raise self._exception
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientPayloadError: DeflateBuffer.feed_data() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

i tried updating all the packages i mentioned before, resetting my token, and nothing works, how do i fix this? (by the way, double slashes are me deleting my pc name)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [mre]; it gives you a chance to isolate your problem and us a chance to see your code.

I believe that you don't need to use aiohttp outside of making your own requests to other APIs because you're already using discord.py which should handle all those things for you

Did you read the error? This suggests some kind of compatibility error..
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientPayloadError: DeflateBuffer.feed_data() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
What version of aiohttp are you using?
discord.py requires this version of aiohttp: aiohttp>=3.7.4,<4
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/requirements.txt
